# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation in linked list

Tags: c, exception, linked-list

I´m creating project as homework for my uni and I have trouble of fixing this error: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. p was 0x1E.

It points me to this line in my code: `if (p->next == NULL)`

Full structure code:

```
void* end()
{
    hlavicka* p = start;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->next == NULL)
        {
            return p;
        }
        else
            p = p->next;
    }
}
```

It is simple function to move through linked list and find its end so that i have pointer for last list because i need to use it in one loop.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Seems ok. Problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Note: if `start == NULL;` you have no `return` statement.

Comment: `start` is probably not what you expect, and at a moment `p->next` points to an incorrect address. I can not say more from so little information.

Comment: Yes, most probably you don't set the `next` as `NULL` when adding nodes to the list. So at some point, `p->next` is not `NULL` but it's rather some dangling pointer, thus when p becomes the invalid pointer, `p->next` is an invalid access.

Comment: Start is initialized always before calling this function as well as p->next is set to NULL when creating list so I have no idea why would it throw this error..

Comment: Guys I think i have fixed it. In other function I did not set up p->next->next = NULL when i used p->next so it would move data to something that was not even initialized that was probably why it threw error. Thanks for your help tho! Appreciated.

Comment: immediately after the end of the `while()` loop should be the statement: `return NULL;` or `return p;`  Also, the caller to this function needs to be checking for a returned value of NULL